# ImageLoader not available

Tags: android

I am trying to use the ImageLoader class from libs-for-android (http://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/), and am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader not available
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839
                                  )
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  579          AndroidRuntime  E  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader not available
  579          AndroidRuntime  E    at com.google.android.imageloader.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:103)
```

(There is a demo app on their website linked above that I am following as an example: http://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/source/browse/demos/jamendo/src/com/google/android/demos/jamendo/widget/AlbumGalleryAdapter.java)

I am trying to use the ImageLoader inside of a PagerAdapter, here is the relevant code (it's the **bind statement** thats causing the exception):

```
public FeaturedImagePagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JSONObject> images) {
        this.cxt = context;
        mImages = images;
        mLoader = ImageLoader.get(this.cxt);
    }

@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cxt
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout featured_image_layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_image_item, null);


        // code omitted from this area that does some setup with the layout above.

        ImageView image = (ImageView) featured_image_layout.findViewById(R.id.featured_image);

        try {           
            mLoader.bind(image, mImages.get(position).getString("url"), null);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return featured_image_layout;
    }
```

I am out of ideas - maybe the ImageLoader class isn't meant for use inside a PagerAdapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ImageLoader but I don't instantiate it like that. I just do this...

```
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader();
```